# Node.js : How can I add meta data to an audio file?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, metadata, mp3, fs

I have a .wav audio file that I would like to add meta data to, in Node.js:

```
let original = fs.readFileSync('./somewhere/something.wav').toString('base64')
let withMeta = addMeta(original)
fs.writeFileSync('./somewhere/something-more.wav', withMeta)
```

Is this possible ? Is there some Js library that allows you to *write* metadata (not just read/extract it) to an existing audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `ffmpeg` on your system, you could use that in node via `fluent-ffmpeg` doing something like the following:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')

ffmpeg('./somewhere/something.wav')
  .audioCodec('copy')
  .outputOptions(
    '-metadata', 'title=testtitle',
    '-metadata', 'artist=testartist'
  )
  .output('./somewhere/something-more.wav')
  .on('end', () => { console.log('done') })
  .run()
```

Acceptable metadata keys for wave files in ffmpeg are: ([source](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/riff.c#L603))

```
  artist
  comment
  copyright
  date
  genre
  language
  title 
  album 
  track
  encoder
  timecode
  encoded_by
```